# How to set the opacity of connecting line in jsplumb?

Tags: css, svg, jsplumb

Please see the working code below. Can someone tell me how to set the opacity of the line connecting the two divs? I could not find anything in the documentation on this. I tried passing `setOpacity: 0.5`, `opacity: 0.5` and using `strokeStyle: rgba(120, 120, 240, 0.4)` as a property in `paintStyle`. None of that helped.

Thanks for your help.

**The code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jsplumb example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .nodes {
            border: 2px solid steelblue;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .div1 {
            position: relative;
            top: 10%;
            left: 10%;
        }
        .div2 {
            position: relative;
            top: 20%;
            left: 40%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='containerdiv'>
        <div class="nodes div1" id="inner1">Inner 1</div>
        <div class="nodes div2" id="inner2">Inner 2</div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.16-all-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jsPlumb.bind("ready", function() {
        jsPlumb.connect({
            source:"inner1", target:"inner2",
            paintStyle: {strokeStyle: 'rgb(120,120,240)', lineWidth: 6}
        });
        jsPlumb.draggable('inner1');
        jsPlumb.draggable('inner2');
    });                     

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two options, the first (that I couldn't make work) is using the [`connectorClass`](http://www.jsplumb.org/apidocs/files/jquery-jsPlumb-1-3-16-all-js.html#connectorClass) property, to assign a class-name, or a white-space separated list of class-names, to the connector elements. But, as noted, this didn't seem to work (or I was doing it wrong, which is possible given the time).

On the other hand, given that the svg elements containing the connectors have a predictable class-name, you could simply style that element directly, using CSS:

```
._jsPlumb_connector  {
    opacity: 0.5; /* or whatever... */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vStyR/).

Comment: Thanks. The problem with ._jsPlumb_connector is that it will set the opacity of all connectors. However, your answer prompted me to try out `cssClass` property, which works great.

Comment: Well, I'm glad to have been of some help...and well done for finding the `cssClass`, I'd managed to miss that entirely!